# How can I write this SQL query properly in Rails without declaring the association?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a free standing Question model in my Rails app where the questions are loaded via YAML. I find the right question and load it into the view by creating a SaleQualifier (which has a question_id field), but I have not declared the association (e.g. SaleQualifier has_one question) because this breaks other parts of the site.

Now I'm looking to find SaleQualifiers in my app depending on fields in both the SaleQualifier and Question models - and I'm trying to write the correct SQL query so I can retrieve the records. Can anyone help me understand how to write this effectively, as this is my first foray into writing my own SQL commands.

My Schema:

```
create_table "questions", force: true do |t|
 t.text     "question_text"
 t.string   "answer_type"
 t.integer  "next_question_id_yes"
 t.integer  "next_question_id_no"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.string   "sale_stage"
 t.boolean  "collectable",          default: false
end

  create_table "sale_qualifiers", force: true do |t|
   t.integer  "question_id"
   t.integer  "next_question_id",     default: 1
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.integer  "sales_opportunity_id"
   t.boolean  "has_answer",           default: false
   t.integer  "prior_question_id",    default: 1
   t.integer  "collection_id"
 end
```

My Question.rb:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :next_question_id_yes, :question_text, :answer_type, presence: true

 File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/questions.yml", 'r') do |file|
   YAML::load(file).each do |record|
      Question.create(record) unless Question.exists?(record)
   end
 end
end
```

SaleQualifier.rb:

```
class SaleQualifier < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :answer, :inverse_of => :sale_qualifier, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer
 belongs_to :sales_opportunity
 validates :sales_opportunity_id, presence: true
 validates_associated :answer
 after_save :update_sales_opp_question
end
```

An example question:

```
- id: 1
 question_text: Why does this company need to buy your products or services?
 answer_type: Text Field
 next_question_id_yes: 2
 next_question_id_no: ~
 collectable: ~
 sale_stage: Prospecting
```

What I'm attempting to achieve is to find all SaleQualifiers that belong_to a sales_opportunity, have has_answer: 'true', and have question_id where the Question sale_stage is Prospecting.

What I've tried:

```
SaleQualifier.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM sale_qualifiers WHERE sales_opportunity_id = '83' has_answer = 'true' INNER JOIN questions ON questions.id = sale_qualifiers.question_id ORDER question.id desc")
```

Which results in the following error:

```
SaleQualifier Load (15.8ms)  SELECT * FROM sale_qualifiers INECT * FROM sale_qualifiers WHERE sales_opportunity_id = '83' has_answer = 'true' INNER JOIN questions ON questions.id = sale_qualifiers.question_id ORDER question.id desc
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "*"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM sale_qualifiers INECT * FROM sale_qualifiers W...
```

Can anyone help me understand how to write this query please?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SaleQualifier.find_by_sql("SELECT sale_qualifiers.* FROM sale_qualifiers WHERE sales_opportunity_id = '83' has_answer = 'true' INNER JOIN questions ON questions.id = sale_qualifiers.question_id ORDER question.id desc")
```

Comment: Thanks - I get the following error:  ` SaleQualifier Load (0.8ms)  SELECT sale_qualifiers.* FROM sale_qualifiers WHERE sales_opportunity_id = '83' has_answer = 'true' INNER JOIN questions ON questions.id = sale_qualifiers.question_id ORDER question.id desc
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "has_answer"
LINE 1: ...sale_qualifiers WHERE sales_opportunity_id = '83' has_answer...`